# java data structure can hold different type of element

Tags: java

Is there a data structure in java can hold different type of objects?
For example, if you need use Stack, the element in stack should be in the same type. What if I want a container has different objects inside it?

Comment: You can use `Object` if you want it to hold anything, or use a parent class for all the objects you want to store. Then you can use `instanceof` to process each individual element as intended.

Comment: What about using List<Object>? Or generally speaking: What about using generics?

Comment: Any of them.  Whether or not you *should* do this kind of depends; using `instanceof` would lead me to believe the design is potentially wonky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect opportunity for inheritance. Most broadly you could have a List of objects and any type of object can go in. More specifically if you need a list of vehicles you would possibly have the following:

```
interface Vehicle{
}

class Car implements Vehicle{
}

class Truck implements Vehicle{
}

List<Vehicle> list = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
list.add(new Car());
list.add(new Truck());
```

Comment: This sounds like a perfect example for re-heating my understanding on inheritance, thanks

Comment: Its a super useful concept and very important in java. Glad to help!

Comment: Good answer microsby0. For posterity's sake, you could also mention how we get the Car and the Truck back out using `instanceof`. :)

Comment: What do you mean "get the Car and Truck back out"?

Comment: @Compass - It shouldn't matter. He will still be coding to an interface(`Vehicle`), so, method calls will be resolved to the methods of appropriate objects (`Car` or `Truck`).

Comment: @TheLostMind well, when he wants the `Airplane` that will be invented 2 chapters down the road to `fly()` we're going to have some funny situations then :P

Comment: @Compass - indeed.. that would be the case. :P

Answer (score 0):

Whatever data structure you are defining can just hold items `Object` since EVERY class implicitly inherits from `Object`. However this take a load on your memory be sure to find a way to handle Garbage collection. 
E.g. `List<Object>` or `HashMap<Object,Object> obj;` or something of that sort.
Maybe if you know all the kinds of Objects that will be held in that data structure you can use the method `getClass()` within a switch statement to find out what class the Object belongs to. Hope this is of help to you. Please implement this solution only if there is no inheritance between the Objects you plan to use otherwise use @microsby0 's answer

Comment: what I actually meant was items of type `Object` take up alot of memory. It is useful to assign them to `null` when you are done with them so that they become eligible for Gcollection